# React native FlatList items not changing with state

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a search bar that updates `this.state.data` which feeds my FlatList.
When I type something like tttt in the SearchBar.....`this.state.data` is updated to an empty array....and the console.log you see below `console.log('Populating flatview with:' + this.state.data);`shows that the array is now emptied...however the FlatList does not change to reflect this.
`this.state.data` is definitely changing to an empty array but the FlatList is not refreshing.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
    this.arrayholder = [];
  }
```

this.state.data and this.arrayholder get populated with objects here.....

```
 <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    lightTheme
    round
    onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
    autoCorrect={false}
  />

  searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter((item) => {
      const itemData = item.name.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();

      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  };



renderFlatView = () => {
    console.log('Populating flatview with:' + this.state.data);
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={item.title}
              subtitle={item.subtitle}
              avatar={item.avatar}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
              onPress={function goes here}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
        />
      </List>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

...figured it out.

`this._handleLoadMore` was firing immediately after state was filtered...and fetched a bunch more results from the API to add to state